# How can I make a service that send mails every 5 minutes?

Tags: c#, web-services, smtp, gmail

Hy,

I have a c# program that sends emails with GMail SMTP server and I want to make a service or something running behind that sends this emails every 5 minutes.

Does anyone have any idea how can I make this with c# and asp.net?

Comment: I think WindowsService fits best on your scenario than a webservice.

Comment: Yes, but I want to make it programatically with C#...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options that spring to mind:

1. Write a Windows service. Kick off a timer that triggers every five minutes, and do your work there.
2. Set up a Windows scheduled task ("Task Scheduler" in Vista/Win7) to trigger every five minutes and launch your application.

I'd tend towards the latter. Windows services are easy to set up, but nothing's simpler than no code at all.

Comment: I want to make it programaticaly with C#, no configuration... just a application...

Comment: @Jeff: well, then, a Windows service might suit you.  You could even run a timer from within a plain old application.

Comment: Actually I am thinking now that I can make a timer that calls my sending email method every 5 minutes. But when I quit the application it will stop...  or?

Comment: @Jeff: yes, when you quit your application, its timer will stop, and the method will no longer be called.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look at [Quartz.NET](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/) - a scheduler for the .NET platform to schedule jobs that send emails through Quartz at regular intervals.

Comment: A simple and proven solution.

Answer (score 1):

Websites should be stateless, so implementing a continuous process in ASP.NET is a bad idea. You either need a console app that never quits, or a windows service. An even easier way is to use a scheduler and run a console app. The windows scheduler should be enough to do this.

Answer (score -1):

Somewhat apropos of this:
http://www.boards.ie/vbulletin/showthread.php?p=52903016

The OP in this instance wanted to process XML files but the concept is the same